# hitbox.tv api can't update_live_media

Tags: php, guzzle, guzzle6

Currently I doing a project by using hitbox.tv api plug in to my website. I would like to update my video title during when I'm broadcasting live stream. I using guzzle 6 to send http request to api end point, the following is my code

myGuzzle.php

```
<?php
namespace myGuzzle;

require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException;

class myGuzzle{


    public $params;
    public $method;
    public $endpoint;
    public $body;
    public $status;
    public $errorJson;


    function response($params=[],$method,$endpoint) {

        $this->params = $params;
        $this->method = $method;
        $this->endpoint = $endpoint;
             $client = new Client();
             try{

            $response = $client->request($this->method, $this->endpoint,['json' => $this->params]);

             $this->body = $response->getBody();
             $this->status = $response->getStatusCode();

             }

             catch(ClientException $e){


             $this->body = $e->getMessage();
             $this->status = $e->getCode();
             $this->errorJson = $e->getResponse()->getBody();
                }


    }



     function getStatus(){

         return $this->status;
     }   
     function getBody(){
         return $this->body;

     }
     function getErrorJson(){

         return $this->errorJson;
     }
}
```

updateLiveMedia.php

```
namespace models;

use myGuzzle\myGuzzle;

class updateLiveMedia {
    protected $username;
    protected $access_token;
    public $media_user_name;
    public $media_id;
    public $media_category_id;
    public $media_live_delay;
    public $media_hidden;
    public $media_recording;
    public $media_mature;
    public $media_hosted_name;
    public $media_countries = [];
    public $media_status;
    public $media_description;



    function __construct($username,$acessToken) {

        $this->username = $username;
        $this->access_token = $acessToken;
        $this->media_countries = ["EN"];
        $this->media_category_id = '0';
        $this->media_recording = "1";
        $this->media_mature ='0';
        $this->media_user_name = $this->username;
        $this->media_hosted_name = "on";
        $this->media_live_delay='2';
        $this->media_hidden = '0';
    }

    /*
     * Parameters function(title,descritption) or
     * Parameters function(title,description,countries).
     */

    function update($opts=[]){

        if(is_array($opts)){

            foreach($opts as $key=>$value){

                $this->$key = $value;
            }

        }
        $myGuzzle = new myGuzzle;

        $uri = "https://api.hitbox.tv/media/live/".$this->username."?authToken=".$this->access_token;
        $params = ["livestream"=>[
    [
      "media_user_name"=>$this->username,
      "media_id"=>$this->media_id,
      "media_category_id"=>$this->media_category_id,
      "media_live_delay"=>$this->media_live_delay,
      "media_hidden"=>$this->media_hidden,
      "media_recording"=>$this->media_recording,
      "media_mature"=>$this->media_mature,
      "media_hosted_name"=>$this->media_hosted_name,
      "media_countries"=>  $this->media_countries,
      "media_status"=>$this->media_status,
      "media_description"=>$this->media_description,
    ]
  ]];
       $myGuzzle->response($params,"PUT",$uri);
       return $myGuzzle->getBody();
       if($myGuzzle->getStatus() == 200){
           return true;
       }
        return false;

        } 

        }
```

run update() return the following result

```
{"success":true,"error":false,"message":"host_mode_enabled"}
```

According the documentation provided by hitbox.tv (http://developers.hitbox.tv/#update-live-media) should return something like the following

```
{
  "livestream": [
    {
      "media_user_name": "masta",
      "media_id": "1",
      "media_category_id": "447",
      "media_live_delay": "0",
      "media_hidden": "0",
      "media_recording": "1",
      "media_mature": "0",
      "media_countries": [
        "EN"
      ],
      "media_status": "This is a stream title!",
      "media_description_md": null
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The API documentation for update-live-media](http://developers.hitbox.tv/#update-live-media) describes the response to be expected only when the hosting flag is not being modified.

The other cases would return different types of answers:

1. When host mode is being enabled

   > {"success":true,"error":false,"message":"host_mode_enabled"}
2. When host mode is being disabled

   > {"success":true,"error":false,"message":"host_mode_disabled"}

And an error would also return something different than the documentation, for example:

1. If the **authToken**/**media_id** is invalid or there is insufficient permissions

   > {"success":true,"error":false,"message":"auth_required_token"} or
   >   {"success":true,"error":false,"message":"auth_required"}

When you are updating the hosting mode, you won't be updating any other information (title). Just try to leave out **media_hosted_name** from your query, and watch how description and titles get updated. Users (and chat bots) then can see the updated information.

Let me know if you still are having any trouble with the API. I would need a specific example and could help you further.